# This Module is not compatible with win32 in react-native

Tags: react-native, winapi, npm, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg

I am facing this error while installing

> fsevents

this module is not compatible with win 32.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `fsevents` it's an `optional` module wich works only on `Darwin distributions (Like MacOS)`.

If you really need to use this module, you will need to use MacOS.